# Building a function that can derive a new column of hashes based on other pd.DataFrame features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, hash

I have a pandas DataFrame of health insurance information - names, addresses, DOBs, etc.

I wrote a function that works on a single row:

```
    
def make_hash(partner: str, df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
  """
  For Partner A, df (pd.DataFrame) must contain:
    health_plan_id: str 
    date_of_birth: dt.Timestamp
    first_name: str
  Other partners will have different feature names for hash input and require a new elif block, below.
  """
  if partner == 'Partner A':
    health_plan_id = str(df.loc[:,'ID'].item()).strip().encode()
    date_of_birth = str(dt.date(df.loc[:,'Date of Birth'].item())).encode()
    first_name = str(df.loc[:,'Member Name'].item()).split(",")[1].strip().encode()

    hash_input = health_plan_id + date_of_birth + first_name
    h = hashlib.sha256(string=hash_input).hexdigest()
    print(f"Input: {hash_input}. Result: {h}.\n")
    return h
  else:
    print("No hashing strategy defined for that partner.")
```

Which outputs (values changed for PII):

```
make_hash(partner="Partner A", df=df)

Input: b'B88845204081984-06-11MickeyMouse'. Result: 4d578e1acd7c670193448b84362095383cc13a24249f6c8c92816d79ec3c48d8.
Out[60]: '4d578e1acd7c670193448b84362095383cc13a24249f6c8c92816d79ec3c48d8'
```

But ideally it would derive a new column (`ID`) and add that '4d578e1acd...' value, as well. If I try to use this function on a DataFrame with > 1 row it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

I'd like the function to be used in a lambda that can operate on a `pd.DataFrame` with an arbitrary number of rows, and expect output to be another `pd.DataFrame` with the same number of rows, but features + 1 (for the new `ID` column).

Is that possible? I see several similar questions, but I am not sure I can (or want to?) do this on an entire `pd.Series` given the function above will have some data-cleansing steps dependent on the value of `partner`...

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a small change in order to use the function with a lambda.

```
function make_partnerhash(datarow, partner : str):

   h = 'a_default_value_like_Partner_has_no_hashing_strategy'

   if partner == "Partner A":
      id = datarow['ID']
      ... calculate hash etc ...
   return h
```

Then you can call the function from a Lambda like this:

```
df['HASH_COLUMN_NAME'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_parnerhash(x, 'Partner A'), axis=1)
```

Since you're encode() and strip() most of the columns, you can pack every field you need into a list, encode() and strip() the fields in a list comprehension, and use `str.join()` method to concatenate all values like this:

```
def make_partnerhash(row, partner: str):
    h = 'NO_HASH_DEFINED_FOR_THIS_PARTNER'
    if partner == 'Partner A':
        values_to_hash = [row['ID'],
                          pd.to_datetime(row['Date of Birth']),
                          row['Member Name'].split(",")[1]]
        
        hash_input = "".join( [ str(x).strip() for x in values_to_hash]).encode()
        h = hashlib.sha256(hash_input).hexdigest()
    
    return h
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Series.apply` and avoid `Series.item()` to pass strings in Series into [`hashlib.sha256`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) which expects scalar values. Below translates operations to run on Series and not scalars hence the multiple calls using `Series.str`.

```py
if partner == 'Partner A': 
    # CREATE PANDAS SERIES OBJECTS OR AS ADDED COLUMNS df[...] =
    health_plan_id = df['ID'].astype('str').str.strip().str.encode()
    date_of_birth = pd.to_datetime(df['Date of Birth']).astype('str').str.encode() 
    first_name = df['Member Name'].astype('str').str.split(",").str[1].str.strip().str.encode() 
    hash_input = health_plan_id + date_of_birth + first_name

    # ASSIGN NEW COLUMN OF ALL ROWS
    df['ID'] = hash_input.apply(lambda h: hashlib.sha256(string=h).hexdigest())
    return df
else:
    print("No hashing strategy defined for that partner.")
```

Comment: I'm not sure `.split(",").str[1]` in the member name line is quite correct.  It should be something like: `.split(",", 1, expand=True)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Iñigo's answer, I prefer to create a callable class when a function's output depends on an external state.

```
class CallableHash:
    def __init__(self, partner):
        self.partner = partner
    
    def __call__(self, row):
        h = 'NO_HASH_DEFINED_FOR_THIS_PARTNER'
        if self.partner == 'Partner A':
            values_to_hash = [row['ID'],
                            pd.to_datetime(row['Date of Birth']),
                            row['Member Name'].split(",")[1]]
            
            hash_input = "".join( [ str(x).strip() for x in values_to_hash]).encode()
            h = hashlib.sha256(hash_input).hexdigest()
        # Add whatever you want to this function
        return h
```

You can use this in a function similar to what you've used

```
def make_hash(partner: str, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    new_df = df # Or copy.deepcopy it if you want a new df
    new_df["ID"] = new_df.apply(CallableHash(partner), axis=1)
    return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a separate function for each partner
Change `df` to `row`, its work on `row`.
I didn't change the processing.

```
def make_hash_Partner_A(row) -> str:
    health_plan_id = str(row['ID']).strip().encode()
    # date_of_birth = str(dt.date(row['Date of Birth'])).encode()
    # May be an error with `dt.date`. Replaced to `pd.datetime`
    date_of_birth = str(pd.to_datetime(row['Date of Birth'])).encode() 
    first_name = str(row['Member Name']).split(",")[1].strip().encode()

    hash_input = health_plan_id + date_of_birth + first_name
    h = hashlib.sha256(string=hash_input).hexdigest()
    return h

df['hash_Partner_A'] = df.apply(make_hash_Partner_A, axis=1)
```